# Betting Question - Expected Value, Probability

Tags: probability, expected-value, gambling

**Question:** Suppose there are 2 matches being played. First match is between player A and player B. Second match is between player C and player D.
There are betting odds for each player.

In a scenario like this, how much money would you bet on each time if you have $100 (can choose to not bet some money)? (multiple correct answers)

**My attempt:** I'm unsure how to attempt this problem, but I've calculated the EV of betting 1 dollar on each of the players, and this is what I got:

E[betting on A] = -.1, E[betting on B] = .2, E[betting on C] = 1/8, E[betting on D] = 0

So this means that if I bet 100 dollars on C, I'll have the highest EV. But, that's extremely risky because I can lose all of my money. How do I go about hedging my bets, and making the smartest bet? I'm pretty sure this question is often used in interviews.

Comment: Are the two matches independent? If A does not win does this mean B wins? Similarly C and D?  What is your utility function, if you are very worried about losing your $\$100$?

Comment: Yes they are independent. If A wins (with .7 probability), then B loses. If C wins, D loses. Note, A winning with .7 probability means B wins with .3 probability.

Comment: Can you explain betting odds? How did you get $-0.1$ for $A$?

Comment: You eliminated the data needed to answer the question.  For some reason there is not always a rollback button.  In this case there is not one for the last revision, which was done by a moderator at my request.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose your bets to ensure a profit.  Suppose we bet $x$ on $C$ and $100-x$ on $D$.  If $C$ wins we have $\frac 92x$.  If $D$ wins we have $\frac 43(100-x)$.  If we want no risk at all, we can set these equal.
$$\frac 92x=\frac 43(100-x)\\
\frac{35}6x=\frac 43\cdot 100\\
x=\frac 8{35}\cdot 100 \approx 22.86$$
Either way we wind up with $\frac {36}{35}\cdot 100$.
You can do the same analysis for betting the other match and see how you come out.

Whether this is the best approach depends on your risk tolerance.  Note that I did not use the stated probability of $C$ winning anywhere.  It is just because the payoff odds were set incorrectly that I could guarantee a profit.

Comment: Why do you win (9/2)x if you bet x on C; shouldn't it be (7/2)x? The betting odd for C is 7:2. (You win 7 and get back your 2 if you bet 2 on C and C wins. You lose 2 if you bet 2 and C loses).

Comment: Also, where did the 36/35 come from at the end?

Comment: I said I have $\frac 92x$ if I bet $x$ on $C$, not that I win $\frac 92x$.  Note that I bet the other $100-x$ on $D$, so I lost that. That matches what you said.  The $\frac {36}{35}$ came from adding $\frac 92$ and $\frac 43$ to gather the $x$s on one side.

Comment: The $\frac {36}{35}\cdot 100$ came from substituting the $x$ I found into either side of the original equation.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you. What I'm still confused about is that this assumes that I place x and 100-x in the C and D game. What about the A and B game? Doesn't this line of reasoning assume that I'm putting ALL my $100 into just one of the two games? Shouldn't we be accounting for possibly higher EV from betting some money in both games?

Comment: Once you do the analysis for the AB game, you will find what profit you can make from that one, if any.  You  can then bet all $100$ on whichever game gives the best profit.  As the profit is guaranteed, you want all your money on the better one.

Comment: How did you get $\frac{9}{2}$ and $\frac{4}{3}$?

Comment: @Bogaso:  as I said, I got them from the payoff odds.  We are told that if we bet $2$ on $C$ and win, we get the $2$ back and $7$ more for $9$.  If we bet $x$ on $C$ and win we have $\frac 92 x$

Comment: @RossMillikan Hello Ross, can you please answer some of my questions? I don't understand why we don't need to consider the probabilities of each of the team winnings? For example in the original question, OP included that the "Probability of A winning is .7, probability of C winning is .25.". Do we not need to consider this in our reasoning?

Comment: @RossMillikan Why didn't you consider betting A or B? In your answer, you only considered betting on C and D?

Comment: @RossMillikan Can you also talk a little more about "Whether this is the best approach depends on your risk tolerance. ". How can I maximize my expected payoffs while minimizing risk/variance? How do you reason about this? Many thanks Ross, I really appreciate you for helping the community and contributing your knowledge.

Comment: @SarahV.P:  we don't need to consider the probability of each winning because the result is the same no matter who wins.  I chose the bet split to make that true.  My approach guarantees a win of $\frac {100}{35} \approx 2.86$, which is possible because the payoff odds  of $\frac 92$ and $\frac 43$ (which are no longer shown in the question) are badly set (in the house's view, well set in our view).  I chose to work with the CD match because it looked like the odds permitted this arbitrage to work.  I don't think the odds for AB allowed it, but am not sure.

Comment: @SarahV.P:  OP says that the expected value of betting on B is higher than any other player, so if you want the highest expected value you should bet all your money on B.  Your expected profit is $20$, instead of $2.86$.  Based on the comment that B has $0.3$ chance to win, you would have $0.3$ chance of $400$ and $0.7$ chance of $0$.  Would you rather have that chance than the sure $102.86?$  That is what the risk tolerance question means.  If you could play a lot of times you can be almost sure to come out better betting on B every time and be way ahead.