# Optimal betting strategy for two separate games

Tags: probability, optimization, expected-value, gambling

You have a total of $\$100$. You do not have to bet all $\$100$, and your bets must be whole numbers.

- Team A faces team B — A wins with probability $0.7$
- Team C faces team D — C wins with probability $0.25$

Betting odds:

- Team A — $2:7$
- Team B — $3:1$
- Team C — $7:2$
- Team D — $1:3$

where $2:7$ odds means that if you bet $\$7$ on A, if A wins, then you get the $\$7$ back plus $\$2$ of profit, and if A loses, you lose the $\$7$.

My thinking was that I calculated some expected gain for each one of the teams, eventually seeing that C was the best deal. So then I put $\$50$ in C and $\$50$ in D. I am not entirely sure how to actually do this problem though and any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Depends on what is "optimal", but if you only want to maximize the expected return, then bet everything on $C$, because it's the best one (and giving positive expected return)

Comment: They were very vague and intentionally did not specify what they were looking for. How about if you want to maximize expected reward, while also making sure that you do not lose money?

Comment: I answered this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777086/betting-question-expected-value-probability) before OP changed it entirely.  Are you that poster?  Are you in the same interview group?

Answer (score 3):

Your "optimal" betting strategy depends on exactly what it is that you want to optimise.  A common choice for betting situations like this is to bet on the option which gives the highest expected winnings, provided that's positive, and not bet at all if there's no option with  positive expected winnings. According to my calculations, your expected winnings per dollar staked on each of the teams are:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{team A:}&0.7\times\frac{2}{7}-0.3=-0.1\\
\text{team B:}&0.3\times\frac{3}{1}-0.7=0.2\\
\text{team C:}&0.25\times\frac{7}{2}-0.75=0.125\\
\text{team D:}&0.75\times\frac{1}{3}-0.25=0
\end{array}
Thus, betting on team A is a losing proposition, so you shouldn't touch that bet with a barge pole. Your expected winnings per dollar is greatest for a bet on team B, so if your *expected winnings* is what you want to maximise, you should place the whole of your $\ \$100\ $ on team B, when your *expected* winnings will be $\ \$20\ $.

The odds for the game between C and D, however, constitute what is known as a [Dutch book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_book), meaning that (as long as your bookie doesn't go broke before you collect) you can *guarantee* that you win by placing appropriately size bets on both C and D.  So if you're risk averse, you might well prefer to place a combination of bets on B, C and D which will guarantee that you win (or a least, that you can't lose) but still give you a satisfactory level of expected winnings (which will, of necessity, be strictly positive).

If you place a proportion $\ y\ $ of your stake on $\ B\ $, a proportion $\ x\ $ of it on C, and the rest, $\ 1-x-y\ $, on D, then the amount you will win for each possible combination of winning teams is given in the following table:
\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{winners}&\text{amount won}\\
\hline
\text{A and C}&\frac{7x}{2}-y-(1-x-y)=\frac{9x}{2}-1\\
\text{A and D}&\frac {1-x-y}{3}-x-y=\frac{1-4x-4y}{3}\\
\text{B and C}&3y+\frac{7x}{2}-(1-x-y)=4y+\frac{9x}{2}-1\\
\text{B and D}&3y+\frac {1-x-y}{3}-x=\frac{8y}{3}-\frac{4x}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\ .
\end{array}
Note that the third and fourth of these quantities exceed the first and second, respectively, by $\ 4y\ $, which must always be non-negative.  All of them will therefore non-negative as long as
\begin{align}
\hspace{-3em}\text{(i)}\hspace{3em}&\frac{2}{9}\le x\ \ \text{  and}\\
\hspace{-3em}\text{(ii)}\hspace{3em}&y\le\frac{1-4x}{4}\ ,
\end{align}
and they will all be strictly positive whenever both these inequalities are strict.  The amount you're guaranteed to win is
$$
g=\min\left(\frac{9x}{2}-1,\frac{1-4x-4y}{3}\right)\ ,
$$
and your expected gain is
\begin{align}
e=\frac{x}{8}+\frac{y}{5}\ .
\end{align}
The requirement that you bet only whole numbers of dollars means that $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $ must be integer multiples of $\ \frac{1}{100}\ $.  The only such pair, $\ (x,y)\ $, of multiples that satisfy inequalities (i) and (ii) are $\ \left(\frac{23}{100},0\right)$,$\left(\frac{23}{100},\frac{1}{100}\right)$,$\left(\frac{24}{100},0\right)$,$\left(\frac{24}{100},\frac{1}{100}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{25}{100},0\right)$.  The first of these maximises $\ g\ $, while the fourth maximises $\ e\ $.

Thus, if you want to maximise the amount you're *guaranteed* to win you should bet $\ \$23\ $ on C and $\ \$77\ $ on D.  You will then win $\ \$3.5\ $ whenever C wins, or $\ \$\frac{8}{3}\ $ whenever D wins, and you're *guaranteed* of winning at least this latter amount. You're *expected* winnings, however, will only be $\ \$\frac{23}{8}\ $.

If you want to maximise your expected winnings while still guaranteeing that you don't lose, you should bet $\ \$1\ $ on B, $\ \$24\ $ on C and the remaining $ \$75\ $ on D. The amounts you will win for each of the four possible outcomes are given in the following table,
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\text{B}&\text{C}&\text{amount won}\\
\hline
\text{win}&\text{win}&\$12\\
\text{win}&\text{lose}&\$4\\
\text{lose}&\text{win}&\$8\\
\text{lose}&\text{lose}&\$0\\
\hline
\end{array}
and your expected winnings will be $\ \$3.2\ $. There is, however a greater than $\ 50\%\ $ chance (specifically, a probability of $\ \frac{21}{40}\ $) that you will only break even.

Comment: Sorry for the really late response. 

What is the condition that we have a dutch book? My guess was that when the implied probability from the polls (e.g 3:1 -> .25) for a certain game adds up to less than 1, but not sure why. How do we know that there exists a betting scheme (x and 1-x in this case) that guarantees non-negative profit (i.e dutch book)?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.  If the odds offered against a set of $\ s\ $ exhaustive and mutually exclusive options are $\ n_1\hspace{-0.2em}:\hspace{-0.2em}d_1,$$n_2\hspace{-0.2em}:\hspace{-0.2em}d_2,$$\dots,$$n_s\hspace{-0.2em}:\hspace{-0.2em}d_s\ $ and you bet $\ \frac{d_ip}{n_i+p_i}\
$ option $\ i\ $, then your payout will be $\ p\ $ regardless of which of the options comes up.  The total amount you've bet, however, is $\ p\sum_\limits{i=1}^s\frac{d_i}{n_i+p_i}\ $, so if the sum of the implied probabilities $\ \frac{d_i}{n_i+p_i}\ $ is less than $1$, you're certain to win.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Why is betting on either A or B bad?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera and also why is it $\frac{9x}{2} -1$ and  $\frac{1-4x}{3}$? Can you explain that?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera How did you figure out the expected winnings?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera, also what about the probabilities? Team A faces team B --> A wins with probability 0.7, Team C faces team D --> C wins with probability 0.25? Do you not need these probability?

Comment: I see I must have made a mistake in calculating the expected gain when betting on B, since such a bet actually has a greater expected gain per dollar stake than any of the others.  This means I'll have to make major revisions to my answer, which I am now doing.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Many thanks I appreciate it very much. I hope you can answer my queries such as why is betting A and B bad (as this is not obvious to me), the derivation of expected winnings (like how you came to your conclusions) and also how to consider the probabilities (like 0.7, 0.3 etc) into the reasoning. Once again, many thanks!

Comment: @Sarah V.P. I have now finished the corrections to my answer. When you make a bet at odds of $\ a:b\ $, your stake is $\ s\ $ and the probability of your winning the bet is $\ p\ $ you will win $\ \frac{as}{b}\ $ with probability $\ p\ $ and lose $\ s\ $ with probability $\ 1-p\ $. Therefore, by definition, your expected winnings are $$p\frac{as}{b}-(1-p)s=\left(\frac{pa}{b}-(1-p)\right)s\ .$$

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Thank you for the reply, I appreciate it. But why is this the case? Isn't the expected value for team A winning if I bet a dollar, is $E[A] = ((\frac{2}{7}+1) \times 0.7 \times 1) - 1 \times 0.3$? A $2:7$ odds means that if you bet $7$ dollars on A, if A wins, then you get the $7$ back + $2$ profit, right? I get my bet and profit back. So I am thinking that in general for team A and for a bet size of $s$, $E[A] = ((\frac{2}{7}+s) \times 0.7 \times s) - s \times 0.3$? Can you please explain why?

Comment: The problem is that your returned bet *isn't profit*.  The simplest way of thinking about the transaction is that both parties retain possession of their stakes until the time for the settlement of the bet.  If the odds are $\ 2:7\ $ and you put up a stake of $\ s\ $ then then the other party has to put up a stake of $\ \frac{2s}{7}\ $. Neither of you has won or lost anything until the outcome of the bet has been determined.

Comment: If you win the bet you win the amount of $\ \frac{2s}{7}\ $ staked by your opponent, if you lose, then you lose your stake of $\ s\ $.  The fact that you retain your stake when you win doesn't mean that this retention counts as a profit, because the stake *was already yours to begin with.*

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Thank you for the reply again. I think I can see where you are coming from but I am still a little bit confused. I found an almost exact question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522742/how-much-money-do-you-bet-on-each-team/4522953?noredirect=1#comment9657038_4522953. It seems to me that the authors of the answers seem to accept the premise that you do need to add $s$ back? There seems to be a conflict in answers and I don't know who to listen to. Again I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @Sarah V.P The formula that the author of that question gives is not for expected *profit*, but expected *total cash in hand* after bets have been settled . If $\ M\ $ is the amount of cash you've got before you start gambling and $\ P\ $ is the profit gained from your bets, then the total cash you'll have in hand after bets have been settled is $\ M+P\ $. Its expected value is $\ E(M+P)=$$\,M+E(P)\ $, so a strategy which maximises expected cash in hand after settlement of bets will also maximise expected profit.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Thank you for reply. Should we reason through the problem with the variance or standard deviation also? Technically the first part of your answer, answers the question of maximizing the expected return but since I am betting all my money on $B$, I can lose it all too, doesn't this also maximizes my variance? Is it possible to find a balance between expected payoffs and expected variance?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Hello any thoughts? Sorry if this is annoying. Maximising expected return also maximise losses right? Is there a way to find a balance?